# Airport Express-like hardware for the PC?

Tags: wireless-networking, music

I'm looking for something that I can stream music to, sort of like how I would be able to stream to wireless speakers using an Airport Express.

Does something like this exist for PC users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:
http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=318

Or one of these:
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/speakers-audio/wireless-music-systems

Or one of these:
http://netgear.com/products/home/hometheater/media-players/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Airfoil to use your Airport Express on a PC.
http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/